# BiodiversityR::accumcomp.long function not found

Tags: r, function, package

I am trying to use the function **accumcomp.long** in the Biodiversity.R package in order to adjust my species accumulation curves in ggplot.

However, calling the function **accumcomp.long** gives me an error, suggesting that this function perhaps does no longer exists.

```r
accum.long1 <- accumcomp.long(Accum.1, ci=NA, label.freq=5)

Error in accumcomp.long(Accum.1, ci = NA, label.freq = 5) : 
  could not find function "accumcomp.long"
```

The function `BiodiversityR::accumcomp.long`
returns

```r
Error: 'accumcomp.long' is not an exported object from 'namespace:BiodiversityR'
```

I am not certain whether this is an issue with the package, the way the package is loaded into my R space, or perhaps unrelated to the package simply the format of my data.

My community and environment files are of dataframe class. I have tried loading them as .csv files as well as .rda files, but the error remains.

```r
??accumcomp.long
```

renders "No results found".

I am using R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)

Any suggestions as to what else I could try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, the way to get code blocks is to use code "fences", which are three backticks (`\`\`\``, not single quotes `'''`), and they must be on a line by themselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for a good reference.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're on a version of `BiodiversityR` before 2.12-2, as that is the first version with that function exported (see [5786cc8](https://github.com/cran/BiodiversityR/commit/5786cc8de84e250a1277e3484a39dc72688f6e2a)). `install.packages("BiodiversityR")` (upgrading it) should work, optionally with `dependencies=TRUE` (up to you on that, I don't know if it will be suggested or required).

Comment: Thanks - yes, reinstalling the package did the trick, with force = T.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed the package BiodiversityR and included force = T (as per this thread https://community.rstudio.com/t/could-not-find-function-error-even-though-fun-is-in-namespace-and-has-an-rd-file/91243). I then reloaded the package. I am not sure what force = T does, but the accumcomp.long function now works.

Comment: Odd, I cannot find anywhere in R documentation where `force=` is discussed. It isn't in `install.packages`, and its `...` are passed to `download.file` and `available.packages`, neither of which use `force=`.